# Create a table as another table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a table(ie. test1) as another table(test2).
test2 has all records.
there are some duplicate records like below:

[image]

Now I want to all record of table test2 in table test1 like below (using create command):

[image]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Not sure I understand. You want to create a second table that has all the same records as table 1, except that duplicate records are removed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With MySQL you probably could try like this:

```
INSERT INTO test1(id, name, address, mobile, genere) 
   SELECT id, name, address, mobile, genere 
   FROM test2 
   GROUP BY name, address, mobile, genere
```

or if you want a `CREATE` syntax try

```
CREATE TABLE test1 AS  
   (SELECT id, name, address, mobile, genere 
   FROM test2 
   GROUP BY name, address, mobile, genere)
```